# ASP.NET Core - Registering new Users

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, http-post

I'm adding the functionality of adding new users to my project following this project:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-role-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core/

However, I encounter a problem when I try to Add a new user:

On the Post Method of the UserController:

```
    [HttpPost]  
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(UserViewModel model)  
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {  
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser  
            {  
                Name = model.Name,  
                UserName = model.UserName,  
                Email = model.Email  
            };  

            IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);  

            if (result.Succeeded)  
            {  
                ApplicationRole applicationRole = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.ApplicationRoleId);  
                if (applicationRole != null)  
                {  
                    IdentityResult roleResult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, applicationRole.Name);  
                    if (roleResult.Succeeded)  
                    {  
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        return View(model);
```

I'm getting an error on this line:

```
  IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);    
       if (result.Succeeded)
```

When I put a break here, I see that `result` is null.

[image]

I'm trying to solve it on my own but no luck so far.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comment: unless you really want or need to implement all that yourself, you might want to take a look at my project which has implemented all that for you already https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/cloudscribe-core  https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Comment: Are you breaking ON the result? It will always be null if you are. Put a break point on the if statement.